# Is there any way to have multiple intents code flow in the chatbot created using Amazon Lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am trying to build a conversation chatbot which has branching conversations resulting in different intents being called based on the results. Something like

A

|\

| C

|/

D

So the intent A is the trigger for the bot and based on inputs taken in A it might go to C for further data or go to D. I was going through the documentation but couldn't find anything to implement this kind of interface. How can i implement this kind of chat interface in Lex.

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

This **is possible** by using lambda.

you have to write a middle ware service using aws lambda and then your lex service will call lambda service for the results and that result can be now trigger the next bot using lambda trigger service.

Might need lot of work around but it is possible.

For more information http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/using-lambda.html